# npm install keeps getting hung up

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

So, I have a package that I am working in and it is using node 14.19. We have some other packages at work that use node 16.xx. At some point, I must have accidentally built the 14.19 package while still using node 16.xx. It migrated the lockfileVersion to 2 and caused other issues.

I ...

- reverted the package-lock.json file to the last "good" version with the lockfileVersion at 1
- deleted the node_modules
- reran npm i

However, the install keeps getting stuck here ...

[image]

Any suggestions for how to handle this?